# Separating convergent series into two divergent series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I have the following practice problem from my Mathematics 2 course at EE university:

Do given equalities hold:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}} = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{n+1-n}{(n+1)^2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{n+1}}-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}}$$

First equality is obviously true because it's a simple algebraic manipulation of adding a zero under the sigma symbol. The second one is the one that bothers me. I've had multiple attempts at this but they have failed miserably... I can see that on the right hand side I have two divergent series; both sequences $a_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$ and $b_n = \frac{n}{(n+1)^2}$ are asymptotically equivalent to $\frac{1}{n}$, that is $a_n \sim b_n \sim \frac{1}{n}$. This makes series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{a_n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{b_n}$ equiconvergent $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}n}$, and since it theverges, both of them diverge as well. I know that the difference of two divergent series can be both convergent and divergent. With that in mind, the equality **could** hold.
I've tried introducing the limit definition of an infinite series into the right hand side but this was as far as I've made it. We have:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{n+1}}-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}} = \lim_{m \to +\infty}\sum_{n=1}^m{\frac{1}{n+1}} - \lim_{m \to +\infty}\sum_{n=1}^m{\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}}$$
The reason why I do not know how to procced is that I am not aware of any theorems that would let me bring two divergent sequences into a common limit. I am basically clueless whether I am allowed to say that for two divergent sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ say that $$\lim_{n \to +\infty}a_n \pm \lim_{n \to +\infty}b_n = \lim_{n \to +\infty}(a_n+b_n)$$. If this was the case the rest of the proof would be pretty easy. I can just bring the two fraction to a common denominator, cancel the terms and I would get the first term from the original question. If I cannot do this, I am pretty much clueless on how to approach this in any other way. Would proof by contradiction suffice? Should I try some series tests? Note that at this point in the practice material only Integral test and 4 basic comparison tests have been introduced. Can someone explain how this is supposed to be done? Thanks in advande!

Comment: I am not sure about what you are asking. Is it whether the equality$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{n+1-n}{(n+1)^2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{n+1}}-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}}$$holds?

Comment: Yes! That is the question. Basically I just described my thought process in the question. Can you provide an answer and maybe point out the flaws in my logic? @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: The second equality is false because the right-hand side is meaningless.  Even in the extended real numbers system, $\infty-\infty$ isn't defined.

Comment: I just wanna make sure you understand the point of the problem. Normally, you’d expect the equation to hold because we are just splitting one sum into two. The problem showcases exactly when we can’t do this, namely when we get $\infty-\infty$, which is undefined. Off the top of my head, I think this is the only case where we can’t do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equality$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{n+1-n}{(n+1)^2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac1{n+1}-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac n{(n+1)^2}\tag1$$neither holds nor doesn't hold. It is meaningless. In fact, neither$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{n+1}}\quad\text{nor}\quad\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}}$$are numbers. So, what's the meaning of the RHS of $(1)$? Even if you see them as $\infty$ (which makes sense), then $(1)$ will still be meaningless, since $\infty-\infty$ is undefined.

Comment: I see. But I am simply trying to give an answer to the practice problem. That's why i tried to solve this by considering the limit definitions. If I was able to bring them under a common limit, they I would have no problem. Are you saying that this is actually incorrect/doesn't hold?  
Should I just stop complicating this by trying to deeply understand it and just understand that I can't separate a convergent series into a sum of two divergent series?

Comment: You are trying to solve the problem by writing\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n+1}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac n{(n+1)^2}&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^m\frac1{n+1}-\sum_{n=1}^m\frac n{(n+1)^2}\\&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^m\frac1{n+1}-\frac n{(n+1)^2}\right).\end{align}But here you run into the same problem that I mentioned in my answer: these equalities are meaningless, since $\infty-\infty$ is undefined. If you really have to provide a yes/no answer, I suppose that the best answer is that the equality does *not* hold.

Comment: That's what I was asking! Thanks a lot!