# Is it possible to separate a convergent series term-wise into two sub-series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What are the rules for term wise separation of two(or the more general case of $n$) infinite series:

Given an infinite series $H=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n, a, b) - g(n, a, b)=C_0$ where $a, b, C_0$ being some constants. Moreover, its known that both $J=\sum_1^\infty f(n, a, b)$ and $K=\sum_1^\infty g(n, a, b)$ are convergent.

Can we always state that in this case $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n, a, b) - \sum_{n=1}^\infty g(n, a, b) = C_0$?

Are these rules summarized somewhere (a reference of some sorts)?

Comment: If series converges this implique that subseries converges

Comment: @Mostafa not necessarily. two infinite divergent series can be combined to create a convergent series right ?

Comment: Yes , but if series converges implique subseries converge

Comment: I am struggling to make sense of it. If a convergent series is made of two divergent sub-series, then the series is convergent but sub series are divergent!

Comment: If the series F is *absolutely* convergent then yes it can be separated into two separate series as you describe.

Comment: @nickalh Now I am confused. As I understood from the answer below: As long as $G$ and $H$ are convergent and $F$ is composed of the term wise sum of both, the below theorem holds and they can be written separately. It doesn't talk about the kind of convergence (absolute or conditional) so I assume this is valid in either case?

Comment: I renamed them again to prevent confusion F vs. f(n,a,b).  Please accept my apologies.

Comment: Is the paragraph starting "Given an infinite series ..." a theorem in your book or a question that you are asking?

Comment: No prob at all. But Is my above interpretation correct? If yes we don't need to talk about absolute or conditional convergent here at all (since it causes more confusion). P.S. This is a question I have.

Comment: You asked about rules, plural, about algebra and sigma.  Absolute convergence is one condition which allows us to split H.
My point is merely relevant to your question, but now that I read your comments, my point does not directly address your question.  @mihaild addresses your question better directly in his answer below.

Comment: thank you. I understand.

Comment: Demonstration of one of your points.
Single convergent series can separate into two divergent series.  Note: this link did not assume the separate series are convergent so comes to different conclusions.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4220716/separating-convergent-series-into-two-divergent-series?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a$ and $b$ are irrelevant here.

It is standard theorem about series: if two series are convergent, their linear combination is convergent and to convergens to linear combination of series. It's direct consequence of corresponding result for sequences, which is shown in any analysis textbook (for example, Rudin "Principles of Mathematical Analysis").

Comment: I understand. But that is regarding the addition/combining of two convergent series. But the opposite process i.e. separation of series is where my doubt is.

Comment: You told that you know that both subseries are convergent. If they converge, they converge to something, and cited theorem says that sum of these somethings is exactly sum of the whole series.